# Getting around WFS Feature Count

Tags: arcpy, wfs, features

Im trying to access a WFS where the feature count is limited at each extent (ie layer with 1000 feature with a limit of 100 for extent). Whether or not its to maintain performance or purely just being restrictive, It's preventing me from viewing/extracting the entire dataset at once.

Is there a potential work around? Im thinking of creating a script that will allow me extract features at a smaller scale using a fishnet and export the features at that extent to a temporary shapefile and move on, then removing duplicates features once completed. I am not sure if this is a good idea or terrible one.

Comment: What is the service URL of this WFS?  As a GIS Professional I would not provide advice without seeing its licensing agreement.

Comment: https://www2.landgate.wa.gov.au/web/guest/57 - There are FAQ's about extracting the data, so I wouldn't see it being an issue I dont think - https://www2.landgate.wa.gov.au/web/guest/arcgis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after searching for work a work around, FME did do the job, but automation using the [request python lib](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to download a GML given the "bbox" co-ordinates was much more preferential. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

The limitations on the number of features returned by this system are in place to maintain performance, rather than to be restrictive. If you are a registered user for SLIP you may like to try the datadownload page to see if the dataset you require is available in full there.

The stated 2000 feature limit on the web page is not accurate. For most datasets there is a feature limit of 10,000 or 15,000.

With regards to your potential workaround to extract the data, the method that you have described is sound and many of the Local Government Authorities that have SLIP subscriptions do this on a nightly basis. As for the tools that they use, it varies, one has an FME workbench set up another user arcpy and another has a model set up in ARCmap.